# Routing YouTube Audio to Microphone Input for Microsoft Word Dictation using VB-Audio Virtual Cable in Windows 10

Tags: windows, audio, ms-word, windows-10, dictation

I'm trying to route the audio from a YouTube video to a microphone input that can be used for Microsoft Word’s dictation feature. I'm using VB-Audio Virtual Cable on Windows 10 and have set up the following:

The output device is set to "Cable Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)".
The input device is set to "Cable Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)".
When I play a YouTube video, I can see the master volume indicator moving, indicating that the audio is being routed to the VB-Audio Virtual Cable. I've also set the "Cable Output" to listen through my speakers so I can monitor the audio, and I can see the microphone bar indicator moving.

However, when I try to use the dictation feature in Microsoft Word Online, it doesn’t seem to pick up the YouTube audio. I've set the microphone in Word to "Cable Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)", but it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.